# Motorola Moto X Play IMEI=0

Tags: fastboot, motorola, imei, moto-x-play

I accidentally ran `fastboot erase all` and now the IMEI isn't being recognized on stock ROM. `fastboot getvar imei` returns the correct number, but no matter what ROM I try, it doesn't show in settings or when I dial *#06# (showing as 0). I've flashed the stock 5.1.1, 6.0.1, and the 7.1.1, ROM, but to no avail. My device is the XT1563.

Is there any way to get back my IMEI number?

Comment: If you reflashed the stock firmware and it didn't return, hopefully you have backup of your EFS partition to restore, otherwise Moto repair is really your only option.

Comment: @acejavelin Oh, bummer. I did have several nandroid backups, but I deleted them after hoping to do a factory reset.

Comment: where did you got these instructions from?

Comment: @alecxs https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x-play/help/moto-x-play-xt1562-imei-0-network-t3541302 and https://github.com/motoxplay/stock

Comment: i cannot find 'fastboot erase all' mentioned anywhere

Comment: you can buy SigmaKey or another phone (which is cheaper)

Comment: @alecxs Oh, no that was when I wanted to factory reset my phone and flash the stock ROM. That was the command that caused the IMEI to not show up. I wasn't supposed to do that.

Comment: maybe one of this tools will help i don't know https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3048984

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, I'll give them a try.